# Cloudformation Lists & Strings :: Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am getting the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "Stack ID: stack-qenlamel5rn7p1icu Failure Reason: [Instance creation failed with reason: Value of property SecurityGroupIds must be of type List of String, stack-qenlamel5rn7p1icu creation failed with reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [Instance].
```

The code I am using is:

```
            "SecurityGroupIds": [{
                "Fn::ImportValue": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${EnvIdentifier}-EC2SecurityGroup"
                }
            }, {
                "Ref": "SecurityGroups"
            }],
```

So as you can see I'm using both Ref and Fn::ImportValue together to create a single 'List of String'. I've tried both separate and they work. Namely:

```
1. Works:
        "SecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref": "SecurityGroups" },

2. Works:
        "SecurityGroupIds" : [ { "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub": "${EnvIdentifier}-EC2SecurityGroup" } } ]
```

Together I get the above error. Tried various things like `join` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since this works:

```
Works: "SecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref": "SecurityGroups" },
```

I speculate that the `SecurityGroups` is a Parameter which takes a **list** of security groups. Thus using `SecurityGroups` and `ImportValue` at once will fail, as one is a `list` and the other is a `string`.

Thus you have to **construct a joined list of strings**. One way is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/a6cfc522a1e9f876b75962f5f553c8e5) in `yaml` though. You would have to modify it to `json` format.

Comment: Yes, think you are right about different data types being source of my problem. On holiday at moment, will give your solution a go when I return. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In YAML syntax we do the following:

```
Value: !Join
    - ','
    - !Ref SubnetId
```

This produces comma-separated list of subnet ids.